# Moving an href of anchor with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to move the value of href from one link to another using jQuery.
I have it selected, but I am having trouble injecting it into the new ancor tag. Is there a better way to do this?

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="1">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="2">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="3">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="4">4</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="5">5</a></li>
    <li><a href="6">6</a></li>
    <li><a href="7">7</a></li>
    <li><a href="8">8</a></li>
</ul>
<a class="GO!" href="">go!</a>
```

jQ:

```
var goLink = $('li.active > a').attr("href");
$(.go).attr("href", 'golink');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nEePk/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot have a class called `GO!` so change it to:

```
<a class="go" href="">go!</a>
```

jQuery:

```
var goLink = $('li.active > a').attr("href");
$('.go').attr("href", golink);   // remove "''" from golink
```

**[DEMO JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/nEePk/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few problems with the code, but your general idea is pretty much true.

```
$(".go").attr("href", function(){
  return $("li.active > a").attr("href");
});
```

Be sure to remove any invalid characters from your element's class name. "GO!" is invalid, thought I suspect you knew this since your selector was merely `.go`.

```
<a href="#" class="go">Go!</a>
```